# Duplicity fails with unclear duplicity.gpg.GPGError

Tags: duplicity, duplicity-backup

I ran duplicity (v1.2.3_1) (via duply) several times on macOS 13.4.1. After around two hours — without any error and successful transmission of several 100gb via ftp — it fails with an GPG error.

I have no clue what the actual problem is.

```
GPG error detail: Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/duplicity", line 86, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/duplicity", line 70, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/duplicity/1.2.3_1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1575, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/duplicity/1.2.3_1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1704, in do_backup
    full_backup(col_stats)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/duplicity/1.2.3_1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 589, in full_backup
    bytes_written = write_multivol(u"full", tarblock_iter,
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/duplicity/1.2.3_1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 447, in write_multivol
    at_end = gpg.GPGWriteFile(tarblock_iter, tdp.name, config.gpg_profile,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/duplicity/1.2.3_1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 406, in GPGWriteFile
    file.close()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/duplicity/1.2.3_1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 292, in close
    self.gpg_failed()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/duplicity/1.2.3_1/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 277, in gpg_failed
    raise GPGError(msg)
 duplicity.gpg.GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: WARNUNG: Der Server 'gpg-agent' is älter als wir selbst (Version 2.2.41 < 2.4.3)
gpg: Hinweis: Wichtige Sicherheits-Fixes können in veralteten Servern fehlen.
gpg: Hinweis: Der Befehl "gpgconf --kill all" startet diese Server neu.
gpg: "2130C08AD7D1E4FA" wird als voreingestellter geheimer Signaturschlüssel benutzt
gpg: problem with fast path key listing: IPC Parameterfehler - ignored
gpg: Leider sind wir im "--batch" Modus - Eingabe nicht möglich
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

Comment: did you try as the error suggests to restart gpg-agent? `gpgconf --kill all` alternatively you may just actually shutdown/reboot your mac (not sleep/wake)

Comment: @ede-duply.net Yes, agent restart does not change anything. I have this problem for several week and after server hardware reboots as well.

Comment: reads as if there are two different gpg versions installed. try to make sure that only one is used by duplicity/duply (set PATH, remove the other version) . not sure if the warning is the real issue, but think we need to get rid of it as the first step.

Comment: searching for "gpg-agent older than" finds several results like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536812/gpg-agent-is-older-than-us-warning-message-even-after-running-gpgconf-kill-a

Comment: After following your suggestion I get a different error 

```duplicity.gpg.GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: "xxx" wird als voreingestellter geheimer Signaturschlüssel benutzt
gpg: Sorry, --batch wurde angegeben - Lesen von der Eingabe ist nicht möglich
===== End GnuPG log =====```

Comment: what is your duplicity command line?

Comment: Duply generates following call ```/opt/homebrew/bin/duplicity --name ZZZ --encrypt-key XXX --sign-key YYY --gpg-options --pinentry-mode loopback  --volsize 1024 --asynchronous-upload --use-agent --exclude-filelist ./exclude /Volumes/X/ ftp://AAA@BBB/backups/ZZZ```

Comment: "--pinentry-mode loopback" is not needed anymore. you may remove tha from your duply profile conf file. if encrypt & sign key differ, do they have different or empty passphrases?

Comment: one more questions. do the duply gpg tests in the beginning succeed? can you post the output?